# App crashes when UITableView loads from Core Data repetitively, bad pointer?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, abaddressbook

I am making an app where the user selects a contact from the address book and adds it to a table view.

I implemented this by creating an addressBook object, using a peoplePicker, storing the ABRecordID object in Core Data as an NSNumber, pulling the ABRecordID from Core Data and converting it into an ABRecordRef, then getting getting the kABPersonFirstNameProperty.

When the app first loads, it runs fine. Names are selected and added to the Core Data database, but after 2-5 names are selected repetitively, the app crashes with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x3...). This occurs in the cellForRowAtIndexPath tableView call towards the bottom of the code block.

I cannot figure out why it crashes after working a few times. Sometimes it will work twice, others five times.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import AddressBook
import AddressBookUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var contacts = [NSManagedObject]()

@IBAction func addContact(sender: AnyObject) {

    // nav controller
    let picker = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()

    // delegate so we can get the selected contact and info
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self

    // make only some people selectable, others grayed out
    //picker.predicateForEnablingPerson = NSPredicate(format: "%K like %@", ABPersonFamilyNameProperty, "Neuburg")

    // make sure we can see contact info
    picker.predicateForSelectionOfPerson = NSPredicate(value:true)

    // all done
    self.presentViewController(picker, animated:true, completion:nil)

}

// called when user picks a contact to get name
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson contact: ABRecord!) {

    // ABRecordRefID object to use and store
    let contactABRecordID: Int32 = ABRecordGetRecordID(contact)

    // save the contact into Core Data
    self.saveContact(contactABRecordID)

    // reload data to table
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func saveContact(contactABRecordID: Int32) {

    // get access to managedObjectContext through the app delegate
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    // create new managed object and instert into the managed object context
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    let contact = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    let wrapper = NSNumber(int: contactABRecordID)

    // set abrecordid attribute for NSMangedObject using KVC
    contact.setValue(wrapper, forKey: "abRecordID")

    // commit changes to person and save to disk
    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }

    // append the new person to contacts database
    contacts.append(contact)

}

// fetch data from Core Data
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // pull up app delegate and grab a ref to managed object context
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    // fetch data from the database
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contact")

    // create error var
    var error: NSError?

    // return an array of managed objects that meets critera from fetch request
    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [NSManagedObject]?

    // make sure fetch worked
    if let results = fetchedResults {
        contacts = results
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }

}

// MARK: - people picker protocol

// address book object
var addressBook : ABAddressBook!

// check to see if app has access to contacts
func determineStatus() -> Bool {

    // assign status of access
    let status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()

    // handle status
    switch status {
    case .Authorized:
        // create address book if authoriezed
        return self.createAddressBook()
    case .NotDetermined:
        // ask for permission if haven't answered
        var ok = false
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(nil) {
            (granted:Bool, err:CFError!) in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if granted {
                    ok = self.createAddressBook()
                }
            }
        }
        // proceed if access is granted
        if ok == true {
            return true
        }
        // otherwise return false
        self.addressBook = nil
        return false
        // if access is restricted
    case .Restricted:
        self.addressBook = nil
        return false
    case .Denied:
        // new iOS 8 feature: sane way of getting the user directly to the relevant prefs
        // I think the crash-in-background issue is now gone
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Need Authorization", message: "Wouldn't you like to authorize this app to use your Contacts?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {
            _ in
            let url = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)
        self.addressBook = nil
        return false
    }
}

// create address book to use if granted access
func createAddressBook() -> Bool {

    // return true if created successfully
    if self.addressBook != nil {
        return true
    }

    // handle errors
    var err : Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
    let addressBook : ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &err).takeRetainedValue()
    if addressBook == nil {
        println(err)
        self.addressBook = nil
        return false
    }

    // assign addresss book with error then return
    self.addressBook = addressBook
    return true
}

// when app opens. make sure we have permission for contacts
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

}

// =========

// MARK: - table view protocol

// table will have as many rows as contacts in array
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    // number of contacts in contacts array
    return contacts.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // each individual cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

    // contact is one of contacts in database
    let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]

    // get ABRecordID
    let wrapper: NSNumber = contact.valueForKey("abRecordID")! as NSNumber

    // turn wrapper into Int32 type
    let contactABRecordID: Int32 = Int32(wrapper.integerValue)

    // ERROR COMES HERE!!!! get person with record ID
    let personABRecordRef: ABRecordRef = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, contactABRecordID).takeRetainedValue() as ABRecordRef

    // get name from person with record ref
    let firstName: String = ABRecordCopyValue(personABRecordRef, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as String

    // grab name attribute from managed object
    cell.textLabel!.text = firstName

    // give cell to table
    return cell

}

// =========

// MARK: - standard code

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // determine if we have access to contacts
    self.determineStatus()

    // bring up a box in front if we don't
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "determineStatus", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

    // set the title
    title = "My People"

    // register UITableViewCell with tableView
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// =========

}
```

**SOLVED!**

Here is what I did. I needed to use an unmanged abperson ref and unwrap it.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // each individual cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

    // contact is one of contacts in database
    let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]

    // grab name attribute from managed object
    cell.textLabel!.text = getContactInfoFromCoreData(contact: contact)

    // give cell to table
    return cell

}

// =========

// MARK: - get contact from Core Data

func getContactInfoFromCoreData(#contact: NSManagedObject) -> String {

    // get ABRecordID
    let wrapper: NSInteger = contact.valueForKey("abRecordID")! as NSInteger

    // turn wrapper into Int32 type
    let contactABRecordID: ABRecordID = Int32(wrapper)

    // get person ref with record ID
    let unmanagedPersonABRecordRef: Unmanaged<ABRecordRef>? = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, contactABRecordID)

    // unwrap optional ref to get real ref
    if let personRefToUse: ABRecordRef = unmanagedPersonABRecordRef?.takeUnretainedValue() {

        // use unwrapped ref to get property
        let firstName: String = ABRecordCopyValue(personRefToUse, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as String

        // return to table view
        return firstName

    }

    // not good
    return "Something went wrong"

}

// =========
```

Comment: Added the location of the error and entered it into the code block. Towards the bottom in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Is it possible that firstName is nil?

Comment: Found the solution. Posted above. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution implemented in original code. I needed to use an optional and unwrap it.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // each individual cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

    // contact is one of contacts in database
    let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]

    // grab name attribute from managed object
    cell.textLabel!.text = getContactInfoFromCoreData(contact: contact)

    // give cell to table
    return cell

}

// =========

// MARK: - get contact from Core Data

func getContactInfoFromCoreData(#contact: NSManagedObject) -> String {

    // get ABRecordID
    let wrapper: NSInteger = contact.valueForKey("abRecordID")! as NSInteger

    // turn wrapper into Int32 type
    let contactABRecordID: ABRecordID = Int32(wrapper)

    // get person ref with record ID
    let unmanagedPersonABRecordRef: Unmanaged<ABRecordRef>? = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, contactABRecordID)

    // unwrap optional ref to get real ref
    if let personRefToUse: ABRecordRef = unmanagedPersonABRecordRef?.takeUnretainedValue() {

        // use unwrapped ref to get property
        let firstName: String = ABRecordCopyValue(personRefToUse, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as String

        // return to table view
        return firstName

    }

    // not good
    return "Something went wrong"

}

// =========
```